# .htaccess get entire query string to a variable

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm using my .htaccess to rewrite the Authorization header to a get param. Why I do this is described [here](https://community.webfaction.com/questions/7249/is-possible-http-authentication-with-php).

So my problem is that when I'm using a query string when I request my API the old query string is removed from the URL. What I want to do is append a query called "Authorization" instead of just rewrite everything behind my index.php as it's done here.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /api/

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0 [L, QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^Basic.*

RewriteRule ^ index.php?Authorization=%{HTTP:Authorization} [L]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you not using `QSA` flag in the second rewrite?

Comment: When I append QSA I'm getting a 500. Do I have to change the rewriteRule maybe? I'm definitely not a master of .htaccess and rewriting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /api/

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^Basic.*
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !Authorization=[^&]*
RewriteRule ^ index.php?Authorization=%{HTTP:Authorization} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Did you found my question from my tweet to you or is it just luck that you found this question? :)

Comment: Yes I got your tweet and also found this question by tag `.htaccess`.